# How to create an audio ISO file from WAV files?

Tags: 13.04, iso, cd, burning

I use 13.04 with Unity. I would like to create an **audio** ISO file from my wav files. I tried many "solutions", but I only could create bin/cue by brasero.

Is there any solution for this situation without I should burn a physical CD and rip it to ISO?

Thx!

Comment: It is clear what you want to ask, but for the record: "Audio iso" files do not use the iso format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't explain it any better or shorter while being precise enough like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_image#Limitations):

> A CD can have multiple tracks, which can contain computer data, audio, or video. File systems such as ISO 9660 are stored inside one of these tracks. Since ISO images are expected to contain a binary copy of the file system and its contents, there is no concept of a "track" inside an ISO image, since a track is a container for the contents of an ISO image. **This means that CDs with multiple tracks can't be stored inside a single ISO image**; at most, an ISO image will contain the data inside one of those multiple tracks, and only if it is stored inside a standard file system.

Comment: hmm, well, then I can not create ISO ... I'm not too happy ... thx your answer