# safe burning output files in file

Tags: cd

I want to safe Music in an .iso file and don't know how
,
I tried different burner software like k3d and brasero, but they don't let me start since I don't have a CD drive

Comment: You can backup all your data (music, pictures, documents etc) using some of the many backup tools. There is no need to create iso files for that purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an audio ISO file from WAV files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380712/how-to-create-an-audio-iso-file-from-wav-files)